# Remove rows with less than a certain number of non-blank cells

Tags: r

I need to remove all the rows from the dataframe below with less than 2 numbers. That means that only the first row should remain.

```
a<-c(1,"")
b<-c(2,"")
AB<-data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: Be aware that in your example data, because you have mixed numbers and characters and have not specified `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, your columns are of type factor not numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `grepl` and check for digits `\\d`

```
AB[rowSums(sapply(AB, function(x) grepl("\\d", x))) == NCOL(AB),]
#  a b
#1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a logical vector with `rowSums` and subset the rows

```
AB[rowSums(AB != '') >1, , drop = FALSE]
#  a b
#1 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also convert the data to numeric and select rows where all the columns are numeric

```
AB[] <- lapply(AB, as.numeric)
AB[rowSums(!is.na(AB)) == ncol(AB), ]

#  a b
#1 1 2
```

**data**

```
a<-c(1,"")
b<-c(2,"")
AB<-data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```